# How to automatically backup Windows event logs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

There doesn't appear to be a way to backup (archive) Windows event logs automatically via the GUI.  Is there a way via a script that can be set as a scheduled task to do this?  If so, can someone point me to a beginner's article on how to write this as I'm not a script guy.  Thanks!  This would be for Windows Server 2003 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our friends over at StackOverflow show how to do this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661782/simple-way-to-backup-event-log-on-windows-server

Also look on the Scripting Guy (Technet) here: [How Can I backup the Event Log?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/09/06/how-can-i-backup-an-event-log-to-a-text-file.aspx)